# how to do the regexp in javascript for this string?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have the following possible string:
  '*', or '4.*', or '*.4' or '4.35'
all the above format are valid, others are all invalid.
basically, if I don't care the digit or word character, this is what I used in PHP for the validation:

```
        else if ( !ereg('^\*|.*\..*$',$bl_objver) )
```

Now, I would like to add some clientside validation, so I just translate it into javascript:

```
    var ver_reg = new RegExp("^\*|.*\..*$");
    if (ver_reg.test(obj_ver) == false)
```

but firebug always shows some error, like: "invalid quantifier *|.*..*$" etc..

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I'm not convinced your expression is correct, but for the moment just going with what you have.)*

Using the RegExp object, you need to **escape the slashes**:

```
var ver_reg = new RegExp("^\\*|.*\\..*$");
```

Alternatively you can use regex literal notation:

```
var ver_reg = /^\*|.*\..*$/;
```

**That answers your direct question, but...**

As for the expression, well, what you definitely want to correct is the start/end anchors each applying to one side of the alternation.

i.e. you're saying `<this>|<that>` where `<this>` is `^\*` and `<that>` is `.*\..*$`

What you want is `^(?:<this>|<that>)$` to ensure the start/end markers are not part of the alternatives (but using `?:` since we're not capturing the group).

So `/^(?:\*|.*\..*)$/` using the second example above - this fix would also need applying to the PHP version (which can use the same syntax).

I'd also question your use of `.` instead of `\w` or `[^.]` or similar, but without knowing what you're actually doing, I can't say for sure what makes most sense.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks, just found some explanation about this as well:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Yeah, that's a good site - well worth reading and learning as much as you can from it. :)